# cursor stays faraway from the tooltip of javascript graph

Tags: javascript, css

I have made a tooltip for a graph but the cursor is moving faraway from the tooltip. especially when I test it in a big monitor. I have put it here: http://jsfiddle.net/u4daX/15/
In order to see the problem you should make the result window larger so you can see that the tooltip stay with distance from where cursor pointing to. Could you give me any hint of what to do? Do you think I should make changes in this part?

```css
   .line1 {
    fill: blue;
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    opacity: 0.7;
   }
   .line2 {
    fill: green;
    stroke: green;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    opacity: 0.7;
   }
   .line3 {
    fill: orange;
    stroke: orange;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    opacity: 0.7;
   }
```

Thanks

Comment: Position of tooltip counting while you move a cursor, this means you have to look at sources of JS to change it, not CSS

Comment: Rolled back to previous version. @sasha I'm not sure what you were trying to do but it was a very bad question edit.

Answer (score 0):

Position of tooltip counting while you move a cursor, this means you have to look at sources of JS to change it, not CSS.

In source of your JavaScript code you have this lines:

```
div.text( hours + ":" + minutes + suffix + ", " + d3.event.pageY)
    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX ) + "px")
    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY ) + "px");
```

They works with text filling your tooltip and change its position. If you add/reduce the value of "left" and "top" style, you'll get what you want.

**Result**: [**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/u4daX/16/)

```
div
    .text( hours + ":" + minutes + suffix + ", " + d3.event.pageY)
    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 50 ) + "px")
    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 30 ) + "px");
```

Comment: But this has the same problem when the window is wide, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, there is a problem, when the window is wide =\

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`d3.mouse`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_mouse) function to get the mouse co-ordinates, for example:

```
div
    .text( hours + ":" + minutes + suffix + ", " + d3.event.pageY)
    .style("left", d3.mouse(this)[0] + "px")
    .style("top", d3.mouse(this)[1] + "px");
```

Also, you may want to adjust the position by adding an offset onto each value, for example:

```
d3.mouse(this)[0] + 20 + "px"
d3.mouse(this)[1] + 30 + "px"
```

Comment: Did you see the updated answer? You might need to adjust the _offset_ from the mouse co-ordinates that you want the tooltip at.

Comment: Possibly... I have tested in IE9 and Chrome29 and the position `d3.mouse(this)[0] + 20 + "px"` and `d3.mouse(this)[1] + 30 + "px"` looks ok to me. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Hmmm, that's not what I am seeing. You can _edit_ your question (there should be an edit link at the top of this page) and upload a screenshot of the problem.